# QT Creator C++ MSVC15: Missing type specifier

Tags: c++, qt

This code worked before and it stopped without me making any changes to it. Here's my mainwindow.h:

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QImage>
#include "videoengine.h"
#include "tracker.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    void updateCoordinateLabels();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    VideoEngine *videoEngine;
    Tracker *tracker;
    void test();
};
```

I'm getting 3 error messages at the line `Tracker *tracker;`:

```
C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

Tracker is a class that I defined and there are no issues with it according to QT. The type should be Tracker, I don't know why its assuming it might be int.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I expect you have a circular include path where two or more headers include each other. From the looks of it you don't need to include `videoengine.h` or `tracker.h` in `mainwindow.h` at all. Use forward declarations instead.

Comment: It turns out you were a 100% right, drescherjm! I'm stupidly including "mainwindow.h" in my "tracker.h", effectively resulting in an infinite loop. Thank you so much for pointing this out, removing this line solved all my issues. Still confused about the bad compiler feedback though.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't indicated which line in your code the error is relating to. Additionally you haven't shown all the code.

With that in mind, likely culprits:

Tracker might be defined within a namespace, so you need to fully qualify the type in your declaration.

You didn't run Qmake?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. The error refers to the line that says `Tracker *tracker`. I ran Qmake multiple times, it didn't change anything. However, the problem is now solved thanks to the other answer.